# Can I use MATLAB on Windows to compile some .m into binaries that can be run on Linux?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

If so, how shall I proceed? I know how to compile into Windows binaries using `deploytool`. I use MATLAB 2014a on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, using [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) to create a jar file is the only possibility.

Answer (score 2):

There's no supported cross-compiler AFAIK, but Linux is free, VMs are free (VirtualBox) or cheap (Parallels), and most Matlab license variants will allow you to install copies on multiple machines and platforms. (A standalone user license entitles you to four installations on your personal machines.) So you could just set up a Linux VM build box to compile your Linux binaries and MEX files with an afternoon's work and maybe $60.